# discrete mathematics - if then proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

show that for integers x and y,

$$x^2 + y^2 = 0$$

x = 0 and y = 0

My approach was:

suppose x ≠ 0 and y ≠ 0 and $x^2 + y^2 = 0 $

$x^2 = -(y^2)$

Then, LHS is always positive but RHS is always negative.
Thus by contradiction, x = 0 and y = 0

Is this a correct proof? I don't think it's correct because I haven't shown that if it doesn't work for values other than 0, it works for 0.

Comment: I think that somewhere you must use the ordering of the real numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas whoops sorry! edited now...

Comment: Instead of the subtraction, I would (for no good reason) prefer this: Suppose to the contrary that at least one of $x$ and $y$ is non-zero. Then $x^2+y^2\gt 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x \neq 0$.

Since $x^2+y^2=0 \Rightarrow y^2=-x^2 <0 \text{ Contradiction!}$

Respectively, if $y \neq 0$:

$$x^2+y^2=0 \Rightarrow x^2=-y^2<0 \text{ that also cannot be true}$$

Therefore,it must be $x=y=0$.